# Parallax image is not working after I change my html to php

Tags: php, css, codeigniter, view, parallax

My parallax is not working at all after I change my HTML to PHP. It shows black background and not the image of parallax that I make

this is my CSS: style_new.css

```
.bgimg-1, .bgimg-2, .bgimg-3 {
    opacity: 0.65;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 472px;
}

.bgimg-1 {
    background-image: url("../img/ourmenu1.jpg");
    min-height: 100%;
}

.bgimg-2{
    background-image: url("../img/ourmenu2.jpg");
    min-height: 100%;
}

.bgimg-3{
    background-image: url("../img/asianbuffet2.jpg");
}
```

And this is my code on view

```
<!--- Parallax -->
            <div class="col-md-12 bgimg-1">
            </div>
```

Comment: Almost impossible to know what's going on without more information (console/network errors, directory/file structure, etc)... that said, this looks like a problem loading either the CSS or the images. Change the `background-image` parameters on your CSS to absolute (full) routes instead of relative ones... that will most likely do the trick

Comment: already did that, but it still black

Comment: actually it said that Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Oh thank you it already work, it seems that i put script js on below no upper caused it to not get read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a reference issue: try using absolute references to the images instead of relative ones.

This could also be related to some other relative references (not the images) which you are not showing, such as the javascript files being used for the parallax effect. Check those too